# Mouse on one element and another do the action and only the other one has action. (html)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Mouse on one element and another do the action, and only the other one has action.
I want to make a mouse on and change background colour effect, but it works on only one.
Whatever the mouse is pointing on, only one will change the colour.
Here is the code (HTML with JS)

```html
<div class = science style = "position:absolute; left:20px">
    <script language="javascript">
        function hightback() {
            document.getElementById("part1").style.backgroundColor = "#744e4e";
        }
        function removehightback() {
            document.getElementById("part1").style.backgroundColor = "#524c44";
        }
    </script>
    <button id = "part1" onclick="window.location.href='science.html';" value="science" onmouseover="hightback()" onmouseout="removehightback()">
        <div class = science1 style = "position:absolute; left:40px; top:45px;">
            <h1>Science</h1>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>

<div class=art style="position:absolute; left:280px">
    <script language="javascript">
        function hightback() {
            document.getElementById("part2").style.backgroundColor = "#744e4e";
        }
        function removehightback() {
            document.getElementById("part2").style.backgroundColor = "#524c44";
        }
    </script>
    <button id="part2" onclick="window.location.href='art.html';" value="art" onmouseover="hightback()" onmouseout="removehightback()">
        <div class=art1 style="position:absolute; left:40px; top:45px;">
            <h1>Art</h1>
        </div>
    </button>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```css
.science1 h1 {
    color: #b6ab8f;
    size: 55;
    font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}

.science button {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #524c44;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 230px;
  height: 300px;
}

.art1 h1 {
    color: #b6ab8f;
    size: 55;
    font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}

.art button {
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #524c44;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 230px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You overwrite your functions for `part2`. Why not make one unique function for all elements?

Please check below example:

```js
function changeBgColor(id, color) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

And now you can use them in such way

```html
<button id="part1"
        onclick="window.location.href='art.html';"
        value="art"
        onmouseover="changeBgColor('part1', '#744e4e')" 
        onmouseout="changeBgColor('part1', '#524c44')" >

  <div class=art1 style="position:absolute; left:40px; top:45px;">
    <h1>Art</h1>
  </div>

</button>

<button id="part2" 
        onclick="window.location.href='art.html';" 
        value="art" 
        onmouseover="changeBgColor('part2', '#744e4e')" 
        onmouseout="changeBgColor('part2', '#524c44')" >

  <div class=art1 style="position:absolute; left:40px; top:45px;">
    <h1>Art</h1>
  </div>

</button>
```

Also you can simplify your code and instead of js use css styles

```css
#part1, #part2 {
   backgound-color: #524c44;    
}

#part1:hover, #part2:hover {
   backgound-color: #744e4e;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now the problem had been fixed.

Comment: In case my answer helped you, you can mark it as the right solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is overlapping JS code as it is calling the second version of the function in the next script tag. I suggest using css hover instead.

*Example:*

```
#part_1:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```